# How can I make objects transparent but thick at the same time

Tags: materials

I am making my own james bond gunbarrel sequence, and when the blood droops down, it needs to look thick but transparent at the same time. I am wondering how to achieve this affect. To understand what I mean entirely, please check out the casino royale gunbarrel sequence on youtube. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean like thick glass?

Answer (score 4):

"Transparent but thick" would sometimes mean "translucent", I suppose. However, the casino royale gunbarrel sequence effect on YouTube seems not. I think you are trying to make things like this:

[image]
[image]

Or something more controllable:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make it look more like your first image. Could you show me how to accomplish this effect?

Comment: @user2227 I wonder what I can help you more. There are two demo file links in my answer, don't miss them. :) (Or you are trying to make the material in Blender Internal render?)